# Помогите с решением ошибок С++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, указатели

Даны два массива: А[M] и B[N] (M и N вводятся с клавиатуры). Необходимо создать третий
массив минимально возможного размера, в котором нужно собрать элементы массива A,
которые не включаются в массив B, без повторений.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<iomanip>
#include"Header.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    srand(time(0));
    //Zadanie 1
    int M, N;
    cin >> M >> N;
    int* A = new int[M];
    int* B = new int[N];
    setArray(A, M);
    setArray(B, N);
    printArray(A, M);
    printArray(B, N);

    bool* isFounA = new bool[M] {false};

    for (size_t i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (size_t q = 0; q < N; q++)
        {
            if (A[i] == B[q])
            {
                isFounA[i] = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (size_t q = i + 1; q < M; q++)
        {
            if (A[i] == A[q])
            {
                isFounA[i] = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    int countNotFound = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        if (!isFounA[i])
            countNotFound++;
    }
    int* C = new int[countNotFound];
    int ci = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        if (!isFounA[i])
        {
            C[ci] = A[i];
            ci++;
        }
    }
    printArray(C, ci);
}
```

Не могу понять, почему не выводится значение 3 массива, уже 2 день сижу и не понимаю.

Вот Header.

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

void setArray(int* a, int size, int mindiap = 0, int maxdiap = 9)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        a[i] = rand() % (maxdiap - mindiap + 1) + mindiap;
    }

}
void printArray(int* a, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

СПАСИБО, Я СМОГ СДЕЛАТЬ!!!

Comment: Наверняка в С++ есть отладка. Воспользуйтесь ей, чтобы не гадать на кофейной гуще

Comment: А вы не хотите воспользоваться возможностями стандартной библиотеки С++? Например, `set_difference`? Или запрещено условием?

Comment: Это задача с идет как дз, и мы выучили только эти библиотеки, если, что я начинающий программист.

Comment: пройдя по отладке, никаких ошибок не выдается, поэтому я не понимаю, в чем проблемма.

Comment: @NightSoul а что вы подразумеваете по словом "отладка"?

Comment: ну F10 и прохожу по коду, меня не устраивает только конечное, но я не могу найти, в чем проблемма. Именно поэтому я написал сюда...

Comment: проблема может быть в вашем хедере с ```printArray```

Comment: @verybadcoder я добавил код хедера

Answer (score 2):

Не пишите в заголовочном файле определения функций, в многофайловом проекте будут проблемы.

А теперь по делу.

Какие размеры массивов у вас? Какие вы выводите?

```
printArray(A, N);
printArray(B, M);
```

а надо

```
printArray(A, M);
printArray(B, N);
```

И массив `isFounA` у вас не инициализирован, так что заполнен мусором, в основном воспринимаемым как значения `true`.

```
bool* isFounA = new bool[M] {false};
```

Попробуйте внести эти изменения и попробовать еще раз.